# foreach loop php with html option tags in shopping cart

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-select, cart

MYSQL query:

```
$sql_product = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id= $product_id";
        $sql_result = $dbh->query($sql_product);
```

PHP:

```
    foreach($sql_result as $row)
        {
        $product_id=$row['product_id'];
        $product_name=$row['product_name'];
        $price=$row['price'];
        $picture=$row['picture'];

        // output
        echo "
        <div>$product_name</div>
        <div>$price</div>
        <div>
            <form action='cart.php' method='POST' id='buy'> 
                Amount: <select name='amount'>
                         <option value='1'>1</option>
                         <option value='2'>2</option>
                         <option value='3'>3</option>
                    </select>                   

            </form>
        </div>
        ";
        if (isset($_POST['amount']))
            {
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
            echo $amount, '<br /><br />';
            }
        }
    echo "<button type='submit'class='btn btn-primary' form='buy'>Buy</button>";
```

I have a problem with the option tag in the PHP foreach loop. It's a shopping cart where there is an HTML option tag inside a form. The value from the option tag is then made into a variable called $amount. But whenever I press the button the amount changed for all the products in the shopping cart. So if I have 3 products in the cart and I want to buy 1 of the first and 2 of the second and third, then the variable $amount changes to 1 for all products. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

add a counter or something in the for loop.

something like

```
$x=0;
foreach() {

     //your code here

     <form action='cart.php' method='POST' id='buy'> 
            Amount: <select name='amount'".$x.">
                     <option value='1'>1</option>
                     <option value='2'>2</option>
                     <option value='3'>3</option>
                </select>                   

        </form>

      //your code here

      $x++;

}
```

instead of creating $x you could try with $row. you just have to add something to the 
`name='amount'".$variable."'>`

if you would change your foreach

```
 foreach($sql_result as $row)
```

to

```
 foreach($sql_result as $k => $row)
```

you could use that $k

```
`name='amount'".$k."'>`
```

**////* UPDATE *////**

as sayd in the comments the problem could be that the form gets created in the foreach. So I recommend to create it outside. This is how you could do it. There are a few changes, try to find them all.

```
// output is only $html at the end //
$html = '<form action="cart.php" method="POST" id="buy">';
foreach($sql_result as $row) {
    $product_id=$row['product_id'];
    $product_name=$row['product_name'];
    $price=$row['price'];
    $picture=$row['picture'];

    $html.='
        <div>$product_name</div>
        <div>$price</div>
        <div>

                Amount: <select name="amount'.$row.'">
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
        </div>';
        if (isset($_POST['amount'])) {
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
            $html.= $amount.'<br /><br />'; //here string concatennation in php is with .
        }
}
$html.='<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="buy">Buy</button>';
$html.='</form>';

// output happends here
echo $html;

// now all of this above you could wrap in a function and then
// return $html;
```

Comment: it stays the same way.. is there maybe a way to have the form with the select tag in the loop and have a variable or something that changes for every product in the cart?

Comment: it should change! maybe there is something else wrong. can you wrap your <form> also around the button, and there is a space missing between submit and class type='submit'class='btn btn-primary'

Comment: should I change something is the this part: if (isset($_POST['aantal']))
    {
    $aantal = $_POST['aantal'];
    echo "aantal: ", $aantal, '<br /><br />';
    }
   ??

Comment: sorry, aantal is amount in dutch

Comment: var_dump($_POST); and see what aantal looks like

Comment: I now have 2 product in the shopping cart and the var_dump says they are the same when I press the button..

Comment: ok, probably because you create the form inside the foreach loop, I'll update the answer

Comment: it still gives me the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the same id (buy) to all the forms you are creating inside the loop and there should be only one id per page.
Do something like:

```
<form action='cart.php' method='POST' id='buy_$row@index'>
```

and put the button inside the loop, with the correct for id:

```
echo "<button type='submit'class='btn btn-primary' form='buy_$row@index'>Buy</button>";
```

Comment: what does 'buy_$row@index' do?  it gives me the following notice: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/erik/public_html/winkelwagentje.php on line 67. and the amount of product remains the same for all products.

Comment: Use your counter variable instead ($x), the key here is to build a unique number to add to buy to create a unique id identifier, like: id='buy_$x' (buy_0, buy_1, etc). Sorry for the construction I used in my previous response. It is for smarty.

Comment: maybe im not getting what you mean. i tried the exact thing you wrote but is still doesnt work.. sorry im new to this

Comment: I am not sure what is the logic behind your code. What you want to happen when user select a quantity in the drop down list? What you want to happen when user clicks on "buy" button? The solution will depend on those answers.